# Offline Ad-Hoc deployment of iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I have registered about 80 devices to my Apple Developer account. Now I want to be able to deploy my app to them in an environment where both XCode and device have no Internet connection. The problem being that if I deploy the app via XCode, the device must have network connection to verify the developer profile. (installed automatically when deploying the app via XCode)

How can I do this? I can setup XCode and the devices with Internet connection, but after the initial setup, developers will have to be able to make changes to the code and re-deploy the app onto the devices all without a network connection.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a while to compile, but you could build,sign and package the app for Ad Hoc deployment, then install it via iTunes.

Steps:

1. In Xcode set the scheme's device to *Generic iOS Device*.
2. Then in the top menu: Product -> Archive.
3. ...it takes a while to compile...
4. In the Organizer (pops up after build completes, or found in Window -> Organizer) select the build and click the *Export* button on the right hand side (under the big *Upload to App Store...* button).
5. Select *Save for Ad Hoc Deployment* and continue.
6. ...You should get a `.ipa` file...
7. Open the `.ipa` file, which should open iTunes.
8. Plug your device into the computer via a lightning cable.
9. In iTunes go to the device then apps.
10. Click on the *Install* button next to the app in the apps list, so it says *Will Install*.
11. Click *Apply*.
12. All things going well you should have the app on the device!

If you then can't open the app you may find the device was not included in the provisioning profile, and you'll need to have some fun in the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/).

Comment: so is there not a way to install/verify the developer certificate before, and from then on it is always trusted?